# Getting error "createStackNavigator is not a function" when trying to implement React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I've been trying to learn React Native by following this tutorial series and am stuck with react native navigation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uIftiPLsC4&list=PLYxzS__5yYQlHANFLwcsSzt3elIbYTG1h&index=21

On the iPhone simulator, I'm getting this error:

```
(0, _reactNavigation.createStackNavigator) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNavigation.createStackNavigator)({
    home: App,
    test: Test
})', '(0, _reactNavigation.createStackNavigator)' is undefined)
```

And on Android, I'm getting this error:

```
Properties can only be defined on Objects.
```

This is the code I have in App.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Platform, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          This is App component!
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('test')} title="Go to Test"></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          This is Test component!
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home')} title="Go to App"></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

export default createStackNavigator({
  home: App,
  test: Test
})
```

It's basically just copied from the tutorial but the only way I could get it to display anything is if I remove the following from the bottom

```
export default createStackNavigator({
  home: App,
  test: Test
})
```

and add export default back to App, but then obviously navigation won't work.

I've installed react-navigation and react-native-gesture-handler (linked too) and added the lines to android MainActivity.java as specified in the docs.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are `react-navigation` v-3 then you have to add  `createAppContainer`

Like this way. It works. Check in here https://snack.expo.io/@masukhelal/navigation-example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Platform, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          This is App component!
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('test')} title="Go to Test"></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          This is Test component!
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home')} title="Go to App"></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  home: App,
  test: Test
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the error persists. When I installed react navigation and gesture handler, I saw [these warnings](https://imgur.com/a/SEIUTTe)

Comment: Hey @Joseph Mok, check this link https://snack.expo.io/@masukhelal/navigation-example. Your code is working. Have you clear the cache and tried it?

Comment: Got it working! I realized react-navigation was at 1.6.1 so I updated it to 3.8.1. Also cleared cache with `react-native run-android -- --reset-cache` Thank you very much for your help!